# Split string into column with regular expression

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently working on an SQL Server and has a following column "CALCULATIONS":

```
CALCULATION
---------------------
((Para_101+Para_202)-Para_3))-1
Para_101*Para_4+CONST
```

These are literally some formulas and I want to extract all the parameters into a column, namely the expected result:

```
RESULT
---------
Para_101
Para_202
Para_3
Para_4
```

Whats the best way to achieve this? I suppose that I should utilise regular expression to do the job, but functions like REGEX_SPLIT are not available in SQL Servers. Also, STRING_SPLIT seems to be difficult to use as it only allows one char as delimiter

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: If the formulas are all of the same structure it could be done with a string processor like regex. If any arbitrary formula is valid it's much more complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option using `translate()`

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([CALCULATION] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('((Para_101+Para_202)-Para_3))-1')
,('Para_101*Para_4+CONST')
 
Select Distinct Value
 from @YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values (translate(Calculation,'()+-*/','      ') )) B(str)
 Cross Apply string_split(str,' ') C
 Where C.value<>''
   and try_convert(money,value) is null
   and C.value not in ('CONST')
```

**Results**

```
Para_101
Para_202
Para_3
Para_4
```

Comment: Nice, but why MONEY :)

Comment: @siggemannen  Dealer's Choice.  Money tends to be a little more forgiving and 4 decimals is usually enough.

Comment: That's fair,it does handle the currency chars

Comment: This is a very cool idea! Thank you very much